# mailgun e-mail attachment cronjob

Tags: bash, ubuntu, cron, mailgun

I have a bash script with the below content, It works fine when i run it directly, If i add this to cron job it fails in attachment.

```
    #!/bin/bash
echo "Clearing the files"
rm -f ci/assets/*.csv
sleep 10
echo "Shot report..."
node ci/export-shot.js
echo "Not shot report..."
node ci/export-not-shot.js
echo "Retouching delivered report..."
node ci/export-retouching-delivered.js
echo "Sending email"
curl -s --user 'api:key-6gdgdfg852fgggy4893g-t5cjgfseerwefgfdgdf2183' \
https://api.mailgun.net/v3/test.co/messages \
-F from='Openly Report Bot <report-bot@test.co>' \
-F to='kirthan.b@test.co' \
-F subject="`date -v-1d +%F` : Shot/Not Shot/Delivered Articles" \
-F text='Daily report of shot, not shot and delivered articles' \
--form-string html='<html>HTML version of the body</html>' \
-F attachment=@ci/assets/shot.csv \
-F attachment=@ci/assets/not-shot.csv \
-F attachment=@ci/assets/delivered.csv \
```

Please help me on this.

Comment: try using an absolute path in your cronjob instead of `ci/assets/`

Comment: Have you tried using the `/full/path/to/the/file/` way?

Comment: Thank you absolute path worked